# como selecionar itens em contador while, em php

Tags: php, javascript, while, contador

Criei uma página administradora onde eu cadastro os dados de livros no banco de dados. fiz esse html onde será mostrado esses dados. a matriz irá crias esse bloco "cabtitulo" com todos os livros cadastrados na páginas administradoras, mas eu gostaria que ficasse visível apenas 4 desses blocos. por isso coloquei lá em baixo, a função background-color:green, pra verificar se o meu código funcionou, caso funcionasse, eu colocaria um display deixando esses outros blocos invisíveis. mas todos os blocos ficam verdes, não os maiores que 3, como defini.

```
<div class="cabtitulo"><p>Promoções</p></div>
<?php 
$comando="select * from tb_promocao";
$matriz=mysql_query($comando);
$contador = 0;

while ($contador<4) {
   while ($linha=mysql_fetch_array($matriz)) {
?>

<article class="livro">
      <?php echo '<img src="img/' .$linha["imagempromo"]. '.jpg">'; ?>
   <p><span class="titulo"><?php echo $linha["titulopromo"]; ?></span><br>
   <span class="precode">R$ <?php echo $linha["precodelivro"]; ?></span><span class="preco">R$ <?php echo $linha["precoparalivro"]; ?></span><br><br></p>
   <button>adicionar<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
   <a href="">ver mais</a>
      <h2><?php echo $contador; ?></h2>
</article>
<?php   
      $contador++;
   }//close matriz 

}//close contador    

while ($contador>=3) { 
   echo '<style> .livro{ background-color:green;}</style>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Você está definindo todo o conteúdo de <article> com a cor verde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todos ficarão verde porque a classe `.livro` será aplicada a todos os `<article class="livro">`. Além do que esse `while` para escrever um CSS não faz sentido. Talvez um `if`, mas mesmo assim não é a melhor prática.

Eu sugeria em vez de fazer como está fazendo, inclua no seu CSS a classe `.livro`:

```
.livro{
    background-color:green;
}
```

E no `while` colocar a verificação direto na tag `article` que irá adicionar a classe caso o `$contador` seja maior ou igual a 3:

```
<article<?php if($contador>=3){echo ' class="livro"';} ?>>
```

O resultado seria a tag:

```
<article class="livro">
```

Comment: Obrigada, me ajudou muito!!

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer algo assim:

Criar a classe que irá definir a cor:

```
.corContador { background-color: #0f0; }
```

Dentro do loop, verificar o contador e atribuir a classe:

```
<div class="<?php $contador < 3 ? 'corContador' : '' ?>">
    <!-- seus dados -->
</div>
```

Comment: funcionou, obrigada!!

Comment: 1) É interessante você marcar uma das duas respostas como "resolvido"

Comment: 2) Suas perguntas tem uma relação bem próxima com algo em que estive trabalhando chamado Plataforma Livros Viajantes. Você tem interesse em conversar mais a respeito? Se sim, pode me contactar pelo e-mail gustavo.adolfo.as@gmail.com. Sucesso!